# how would you implement an interface in java example calculator

Tags: java

I've got a Calculator interface that contains

```
public interface Calculator {

    public void setOperator(char operator);         
    public void setOperand (double operand);  
    public double getResult();
}
```

How would i implement this in another class, for a basic calculator???

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that implements the Calculator interface and implement all the methods as desired.

```
public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {
    public void setOperator(char operator) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("implement me.");
    }         
    public void setOperand (double operand) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("implement me.");
    }  
    public double getResult() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("implement me.");
    }
}
```

Comment: a) very funny, ha ha b) The XyzImpl Naming convention is awful. How about DefaultCalculator, StandardCalculator etc?